# How to type an object where function parameters are altered?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to make a method that receives an object where the values are methods, and it alters these methods by removing their first parameter. I almost got it working, but for some reason the function parameters and their return values are assigned randomly:

```
const obj = {
  f1: (p11: string, p12: number) => 5,
  another: (p21: string, p22: number) => "drt",
  aVoid: (p31: string, p32: string) => {}
}

// removes the first argument of a function
type CutFirstArg<F> = F extends (_: any, ...tail: infer TT) => infer R
  ? (...args: TT) => R
  : never

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]

function test<T, K extends CutFirstArg<ValueOf<T>>>(theObject: T){
  const result = {}
  // some code that automatically alters the first param, this is just an example
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(theObject)) {
    (result as any)[key] = value.bind(null, "firstArmAddedManually", value.arguments.shift())
  }
  return result as Record<keyof T, K>
}
// this produces an error
const f1 = test(obj).another(21)
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=33&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBGARgKzgXjgb2HOAzARgC44AKABwOLlgCcBLCAcwBo5KAmEiAVwFtEAU1oBKdAD44AVhY44AQwhgYAC2EkKHanUat2HLnF4DhYtJIBEAE1owLs3PIBqYelY3kAzNpgNmbL0MdZjNJTABfYEjgAHoYuFpBPjAAN0EoOFVBfHpaWAVaJn5BCHgwPAV8HggQGHpIYBgAT3JsgGEeGAAxXNgAQUKAHi7JDC64QQAPGBKrDNIAfRJFJrYAOg2YeXoAGxJGPGE4ABVj0LgDo4AlOQB%20Mg21%20UKoElPzm9xuQTTaYEaWtknPIdjxBAB5PCDY6jE4AbQA1oImuUTgBdf54aq1eoQTLpGDQtgAaQm01mGQ63V6MAGTEGwNBEKhMPE4lIWXBKEEtTeImwuHA0HgiSgPB28AwETkcRoYD42XAVmyqnk8HknXlavoIBBOyaCglwgyWRyeXg5Ge8j4bFU9Ay9rgyB4%20UUZOt5B2gjkeDAtDIQvyiORbBSILBaIQFS5yB5MDWJV89HSHLUMbjIjEAtwZFF4vVGRWImDTUjGDDTLWiEYVlIvB2OzYFjwNIGfD6VmVVgAsooeHqmvY4BWwU9CsVSlA1lAVPQ8DBSJm5JFcIkYDxaHi8xKFBkrjy-VZBkiURVjiTxFFYvEAAIwKAAWimrVqT9otD9u6soEg%20UI6HxWBSCQZARCeJQsloUgtBEYAgA)

How should I type this properly? (also is there a simpler solution? This code looks like spaghetti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new `ObjWithCutFirstArg` type based on your `CutFirstArg` type. It's a mapping that basically maps functions to their cut version, and any other value just to themselves, to keep non-function fields of the object intact, in case you care:

```js
const obj = {
    f1: (p11: string, p12: number) => 5,
    another: (p21: string, p22: number) => "drt",
    aVoid: (p31: string, p32: string) => { },
    manyArguments: (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => true,
    varargFunc: (a: number, b: string, ...c: boolean[]) => false as const,
    noFunction: 123,
}

type ObjWithCutFirstArg<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (_: any, ...tail: infer TT) => infer R // if a function
        ? (...args: TT) => R // cut first argument
        : T[K]; // or use the original value
};

function test<T>(theObject: T): ObjWithCutFirstArg<T> {
    const result = {};
    // some code that automatically alters the first param, this is just an example
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(theObject)) {
        (result as any)[key] = value.bind(null, "firstArmAddedManually", value.arguments.shift())
    }
    return result as any;
}

const mapped = test(obj);
const f1: string = mapped.another(21);

const forIntellisense = { ...mapped };
```

The intellisense for `mapped` displays the following:

[image: Resulting type for mapped]

Which, when looking at `forIntellisense`, actually means the following:

[image: Resulting type for forIntellisense]

Answer (score 1):

Your version doesn't work because `T[keyof T]` produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the property values in `T`, which in your case will be a union of functions.  The keys have been forgotten, and any mapping between each key and each function is gone.

What you want instead is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which keeps track of this, like `{[K in keyof T]: CutFirstArg<T[K]>}`, in which each property key `K` from `theObject`'s type is kept, and each property value `T[K]` is transformed via `CutFirstArg`.

---

My typing for this would look like:

```
function test<T extends Record<keyof T, (arg1: string, ...args: any) => any>>(
  theObject: T
) {
  const result: any = {}
  for (const [key, value] of 
    Object.entries(theObject) as Array<[keyof T, Function]>) {
    result[key] = (...args: any) => value("firstArmAddedManually", ...args)
  }
  return result as { [K in keyof T]: CutFirstArg<T[K]> }
}
```

Notice that I've [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the input object to be something whose property values are functions whose first argument is of type `string`.  This will prevent you from calling something like `test({f: (arg: number) => arg.toFixed()})`  which would blow up at runtime.

I've also changed some of the type assertions, but most noteworthy here is that I've changed your implementation to something that should actually work.  I know you said "this is just an example", but it doesn't work since [`Function.arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) only has values inside a call to the function, assuming it works at all which it does not in many environments.  Anyway, let's test it:

```
const testObj = test(obj);
/* const testObj: {
    f1: (p12: number) => number;
    another: (p22: number) => string;
    aVoid: (p32: string) => void;
} */

console.log(test(obj).another(21).toUpperCase()) // DRT
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-BfR9vPOUaloHgMbgP1MN9giYL9b2cVx3DIQISDAtNoKPCI4GPWIV0gKAwF2QR1l2MAmGFQldxQERniUbJaFILQyJgMAAFVyDaWh2ndTMRDEeI4AAEWuE4ASAA)